# Calculate expected values for a normal distribution

Tags: probability, integration

Suppose that X ~ N(1,2)

Find:

$E(X-1)^4
and  E(X^4)$

I have no idea how to get started. Do I just need to integrate the pdf of the normal distribution multiplied by what is between the brackets? If so, how is this done (these seem very complex integrals). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there anyone who can help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $X^4$ cancels in the expansion.

Convert to 0-mean normals $Y \sim N(0,\sigma=2)$ and use the symmetry of pdf of $Y$ around $0$ to conclude that $\mathbb{E} \left[Y^k\right]=0$ for all odd $k$. That would only leave you with $\mathbb{E} \left[Y^2\right]$ term, but $\mathbb{E} \left[Y^2\right] = \sigma^2$.

**Further hint** To convert to $0$-mean. note that if $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mu$, then $\mathbb{E}[X-\mu]=0$.

**Full Solution** Let $Y = X-1$ and note that $$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \mathbb{E}[X-1] = \mathbb{E}[X]-1 = 1-1 = 0,$$ and the variance of $Y$ is unaffected by translation, so it still is $2$. Thus, $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,2)$ and pdf of $Y$, $f_Y(y)$ is symmetric around $y=0$. Note by symmetry that

$$
\mathbb{E}[Y] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty y f_Y(y) dy = 0
\mathbb{E}[Y^3] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty y^3 f_Y(y) dy = 0
$$

and

$$\mathbb{E}[Y^2] = var(Y) = 2^2 = 4.$$

Now we are looking for
$$\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}[(X-1)^4-X^4]
 &= \mathbb{E}[Y^4-(Y+1)^4] \\
 &= \mathbb{E}[-4Y^3+6Y^2-4Y+1] \\
 &= 1 -4 \mathbb{E}[Y] + 6 \mathbb{E}[Y^2] -4 \mathbb{E}[Y^3]\\
 &= 1 -4\cdot 0 + 6\cdot 2^2 - 4 \cdot 0 \\
 &= 25.
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your help! Could you please show me the full answer though because I tried, but I still do not understand it fully. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: @mause I wrote up a full solution for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help.