# Expected values for normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, expectation

So I have a practice question on an example exam, and I am a bit stumped by it:

Suppose that $X \sim N(1,2)$.

Find:
$$
E((X−1)^4)
$$

and
$$
E(X^4)
$$

I am a bit confused as to how to proceed. Now, I know it is possible to get these using the moment generating function, but for the normal that function is awfully complicated and it's a pain to take all those derivatives. I've been trying to find shortcuts.I found the following post here on the Math exchange:

[Calculate expected values for a normal distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334052/calculate-expected-values-for-a-normal-distribution)

Which purports to answer the question. However, I am confused by the last step. This is what they wrote for the solution:

$$
[(X−1)^4−X^4]=[Y^4−(Y+1)^4]=[−4Y^3+6Y^2−4Y+1]=1−4[Y]+6[Y^2]−4[Y^3]=1−4⋅0+6⋅22−4⋅0=25
$$

But how is this actually a solution? This doesn't give you either E(X−1)^4 or E(X^4) individually, it only evaluates the expected value of the difference between them. I understand the algebra involved, but it seems to me this doesn't actually answer the question. Further, searching around I actually can't find ANY proofs online regarding the 4th moment of the normal distribution.

Is it really not possible to evaluate these without the MGF? If not, how do I get E(X−1)^4 or E(X^4) from the "solution" offered at the other thread?

Anyone have any help? Or even any shortcuts for evaluating the MGF derivatives?

Comment: Hint: $X - 1 \sim N(0,2)$, and $X^4 = ((X-1)+1)^4$.  This may help.  The "solution" you wrote in your question doesn't make any sense to me.  $E(N(0,2)^n)=0$ if $n$ is odd.  Not sure what it is if $n$ is 2 or 4.  If $n=2$, you might get a chi-squared distribution.  There is probably a Wikipedia of Wolfram article on the Web that you can use to find $E(N(0,2)^n)$ for any $n$.  They may use $N(0,1)$, so you'll have to do a little work.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** I am not sure whether $2$ is the variance or the standard deviation. (Some use $\sigma^2$ as the second parameter, and some use $\sigma$.)

So to cover all bases, we assume that $X$ has standard deviation $\sigma$.  Let $Y=X-1$. Then $Y$ has mean $0$ and standard deviation $\sigma$. If we know $E(Y)$, $E(Y^2)$, $E(Y^3)$, and $E(Y^4)$, we can find anything we may need by using the linearity of expectation.

The calculation of $E(Y)$ and $E(Y^3)$ is no problem, by symmetry they are both $0$.

The calculation of $E(Y^2)$ is no problem either, it is $\text{Var}(Y)+(E(Y))^2$, so it is $\sigma^2$.

For $E(Y^4)$, we need to do some work. Note first that $Y=\sigma Z$, where $Z$ is standard normal. So $E(Y^4)=\sigma^4 E(Z^4)$. We show how to calculate $E(Z^4)$. 
$$E(z^4)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty z^4 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-z^2/2}\,dz.$$

We integrate by parts, letting $u=z^3$ and $dv=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}ze^{-z^2/2}\,dz$.
The integral turns out to be $\int_{-\infty}^\infty kz^2e^{-z^2/2}\,dz$, where $k$ is a constant. We can now find an explicit answer, since $E(Z^2)=1$.

Comment: Where does that k constant come from? In fact, how do you integrate that function at all? I have no idea how you are supposed to integrate e^((-z^2)/2).

Comment: (Sorry pressed enter before I finished typing). Anyway, so we get down to that integral but how do you find an explicit answer? That integral can't be reduced, and it lacks the 1/sqrt(2pi) term for it to be the expected value of Z^2.